# Dojo List Text Box - Many values lead to horizontal scrolling - How to stay in table cell?

Tags: dojo, xpages

We are using a Dojo List Text Box element containing many values. Now there are so many values, that it can hardlly be displayed in on row. But instead of staying in the frame given by the table cell, the textbox gets so big, that you need to scroll horizontally to see als values. See:

[image]

How can I force the text box to start a new line, as soon as the frame of our table cell is reached?

Currently this is our text box:

```
<xp:td style="width:80%">

<xe:djextListTextBox id="djPersonSerialLetters"
    value="#{docApplication.PersonSerienbrief}" multipleSeparator="," multipleTrim="true">
</xe:djextListTextBox>

</xp:td>
```

Comment: It looks like it's the table that expands. Try setting a width on the table itself

Comment: Even if I set the table width to 500px, it stays the same size :(